# Can cloudflare add custom headers?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, cloudflare

Is there any way to add custom headers in cloudflare?

We have some https ajax to cache static files,
but it's not handling headers like "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" in response header and cause failure on chrome.

Answer (score 11):

Scott Helme has published a way to do it using new recently released Cloudflare Workers.

https://scotthelme.co.uk/security-headers-cloudflare-worker/

> ```
> let securityHeaders = {
>   "Content-Security-Policy": "upgrade-insecure-requests",
>   "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=1000",
>   "X-Xss-Protection": "1; mode=block",
>   "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
>   "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
>   "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
> }
>
> let sanitiseHeaders = {
>   "Server": "My New Server Header!!!",
> }
>
> let removeHeaders = [
>   "Public-Key-Pins",
>   "X-Powered-By",
>   "X-AspNet-Version",
> ]
>
> addEventListener('fetch', event => {
>   event.respondWith(addHeaders(event.request))
> })
>
> async function addHeaders(req) {
>   let response = await fetch(req)
>   let newHdrs = new Headers(response.headers)
>
>   if (newHdrs.has("Content-Type") && !newHdrs.get("Content-Type").includes("text/html")) {
>     return new Response(response.body, {
>       status: response.status,
>       statusText: response.statusText,
>       headers: newHdrs
>     })
>   }
>
>   Object.keys(securityHeaders).map(function(name, index) {
>     newHdrs.set(name, securityHeaders[name]);
>   })
>
>   Object.keys(sanitiseHeaders).map(function(name, index) {
>     newHdrs.set(name, sanitiseHeaders[name]);
>   })
>
>   removeHeaders.forEach(function(name) {
>     newHdrs.delete(name)
>   })
>
>   return new Response(response.body, {
>     status: response.status,
>     statusText: response.statusText,
>     headers: newHdrs
>   })
> }
> ```

Answer (score 6):

To add custom headers, select `Workers` in Cloudflare.

[image: CloudFlare Workers]

To add custom headers such as `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` or `X-Frame-Options` then add the following little script: -

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  let response = await fetch(request)
  let newHeaders = new Headers(response.headers)
  newHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
  newHeaders.set("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN")
  
  // ... and any more required headers

  return new Response(response.body, {
    status: response.status,
    statusText: response.statusText,
    headers: newHeaders
  })
}
```

Once you have created your worker, you need to match it to a route e.g.

[image: Match route to worker]

If you now test your endpoint using e.g. Chrome Dev tools, you will see the response headers.